# Regex to find the number of extra spaces, including trailing and leading spaces

Tags: regex, perl

I'm trying to count the number of extra spaces, including trailing and leading spaces in a string. There are a lot of suggestions out there, but none of them get the count exactly right.

Example ( _ indicates space)

```
__this is a string__with extra spaces__
```

should match 5 extra spaces.

Here's my code:

```
if (my @matches = $_[0] =~ m/(\s(?=\s)|(?<=\s)\s)|^\s|\s$/g){
    push @errors, {
        "error_count" => scalar @matches,
        "error_type"  =>  "extra spaces",
    };
}
```

The problem with this regex is that it counts spaces in the middle twice.
However, if I take out one of the look-ahead/look-behind matches, like so:

```
$_[0] =~ m/\s(?=\s)|^\s|\s$/g
```

It won't count two extra spaces at the beginning of a string. (My test string would only match 4 spaces.)

Comment: side note; `$meaningful` variable is always better than `$_[0]` and `m` is implicit/not needed for `/../`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
$_[0] =~ m/^\s|(?<=\s)\s|\s(?=\s*$)/g
```

This should match

1. the first space (if one exists),
2. each space that follows a space,
3. and that one trailing space that immediately follows the last non-space (the rest of the trailing spaces are already counted by the second case).

In other words, for your example, here's what each of the three cases would match:

```
__this is a string _with extra spaces__
12                 2                 32
```

This also works for the edge case of all spaces:

```
_____
12222
```

Comment: Of all the solutions, I'm not sure which is the most elegant, but this certainly is the closest to my original statement. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This regex should match all unnecessary individual spaces

```
^( )+|( )(?= )|( )+$
```

or

```
$_[0] =~ m/^( )+|( )(?= )|( )+$/g
```

You could change the spaces to \s but then it'll count tabs as well.

[Working on RegexPal](http://regexpal.com/?flags=g&regex=%5E%28%20%29%2b%7C%28%20%29%28?=%20%29%7C%28%20%29%2b%24&input=%20%20this%20is%20a%20string%20%20%20%20with%20%20extra%20%20spaces%20%20)

**Breakdown:**

`^( )+` Match any spaces connected to the start of the line

`( )(?= )` Match any spaces that are immediately followed by another space

`( )+$` Match any spaces connected to the end of the line

Answer (score 0):

With three simple regular expressions (and replacing spaces with underscores for clarity) you could use:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $str = "__this_is_a_string__with_extra_underscores__";

my $temp = $str;

$temp =~ s/^_+//;
$temp =~ s/_+$//;
$temp =~ s/__+/_/g;

my $num_extra_underscores = (length $str) - (length $temp);

print "The string '$str' has $num_extra_underscores extraunderscores\n";
```